# in unreal engine，trace insights, how can I get the data format of .utrace binary file?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal

when using unrealinsights, the .utrace file will be created，I'm going to parse the .utrace file in java, how can I get the data format of .utrace binary file? or which cpp file parse the format？

a document of the data format of .utrace binary file.
or the source codes generate/parse the .utrace file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.